# PHP - How to print '\n', '\r', '\r\n', and tabs in a text submitted by form?

Tags: php, unicode

All,

I am trying to build a completely UTF-8 web app which allows users to submit text content.

If I store a text copied on a web form (`textarea`) into a PHP string `$str`, and then print this variable, the text is obviously printed without the new lines, carriage returns, or tabs.

Is there a way for me to view those special characters when I print the text?

For example, if the user were to enter:

```
Two roads diverged in a yellow wood,
And sorry I could not travel both
```

I'd like to be able to print:

```
Two roads diverged in a yellow wood,\nAnd sorry I could not travel both
```

Comment: nl2br() is the function you're looking for

Comment: If I recall correctly it is a matter of getting the textarea to actually send the '\n's.  They get discarded by the browser if you don't set the proper attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either echo them into a textarea, or surround them with `<pre>` tags. Otherwise, massage the data with [nl2br](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) and a custom one for handling tabs:

```
function tab2nbsp($str)
{
    return str_replace("\t", '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $str); 
}
```

Comment: ...and remember to `htmlspecialchars` them first too, unless you are deliberately allowing users to use cross-site-scripting exploits...

Answer (score 1):

When you copy over text it should retain carriage returns and new lines in the source code and in any file/database you store the information in. If you're asking how to display it on an HTML page so that it renders with line breaks, try the php `nl2br($string)` function.

Answer (score 1):

use PHP's `nl2br` to add `<br />`-tags to your newlines. http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php

you can also put the content in `<pre>`-tags or use the CSS-property `white-space:pre` http://www.css4you.de/Texteigenschaften/white-space.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<pre>` tag to display a block of pre-formatted text (text with newlines, tabs, or multiple spaces).  This tag preserves these elements.

The function [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br) may also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

use this, when record entered in database this will convert br to nl so i we get back this to html so we have to convert it nl to br....

```
nl2br($str);
```